# When is ¦ not equal to ¦?

Tags: c++, c, ascii, tcl

Background.  I'm working with [netlists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE), and in general, people specify different hierarchies by using `/`.  However, it's not illegal to actually use a `/` as a part of an instance name.

For example, `X1/X2/X3/X4` might refer to instance `X4` inside another instance named `X1/X2/X3`.  Or it might refer an instance named `X3/X4` inside an instance named `X2` inside an instance named `X1`.  Got it?

There's really no "regular" character that *cannot* be used as a part of an instance name, so you resort to a non-printable one, or ... perhaps one outside of the standard 0..127 [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) chars.

I thought I'd try (decimal) 166, because for me it shows up as the pipe: `¦`.

So... I've got some C++ code which constructs the path name using `¦` as the hierarchical separator, so the path above looks like `X1¦X2/X3¦X4`.

Now the GUI is written in Tcl/Tk, and to properly translate this into human readable terms I need to do something like the following:

```
set path [getPathFromC++] ;# returns X1¦X2/X3¦X4
set humanreadable [join [split $path ¦] /]
```

Basically, replace the `¦` with `/` (I could also accomplish this with `[string map]`).

Now, the problem is, the `¦` in the string I get from C++ doesn't match the `¦` I can create in Tcl.  i.e. This fails:

```
set path [getPathFromC++] ;# returns X1¦X2/X3¦X4
string match $path [format X1%cX2/X3%cX4 166 166]
```

Visually, the two strings look identical, but string match fails.  I even tried using [scan](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1497) to see if I'd mixed up the bit values.  But

```
set path [getPathFromC++] ;# returns X1¦X2/X3¦X4
set path2 [format X1%cX2/X3%cX4 166 166]
for {set i 0} {$i < [string length $path]} {incr i} {
   set p [string range $path $i $i]
   set p2 [string range $path2 $i $i]
   scan %c $p c
   scan %c $p2 c2
   puts [list $p $c :::: $p2 $c2 equal? [string equal $c $c2]]
}
```

Produces output which *looks* like everything should match, except the `[string equal]` fails for the `¦` characters with a print line:

```
¦ 166 :::: ¦ 166 equal? 0
```

For what it's worth, the character in C++ is defined as:

```
const char SEPARATOR = 166;
```

Any ideas why a character outside the regular ASCII range would fail like this?  When I changed the separator to (decimal) 28 (`^\`), things worked fine.  I just don't want to get bit by a similar problem on a different platform.  (I'm currently using Redhat Linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, modern versions of TCL use UTF-8 internally for string representation.  In UTF-8, decimal 166 is half of a character, so it's no wonder that all hell is breaking loose. ;-)

My guess is that your C++ code is using a Latin-1 string (i.e., `char *`) and you're passing that to TCL which is interpreting it as a UTF-8 string.  You need to convert your C++ string to UTF-8 before passing it to any TCL C functions.  TCL provides [some functions for this purpose](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.2.3/TclLib/Encoding.htm).

You can read more about [TCL and UTF-8](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/i18n.html).

Comment: NB: Modern means "from 8.1 onwards" and has been this way for well over a decade. Also, the function the questioner is looking for is `Tcl_ExternalToUtfDString`.

Answer (score 6):

Latin-1 has two different [vertical bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) characters:

- 124 | VERTICAL LINE
- 166 ¦ BROKEN BAR

Some older fonts mixed up the two glyphs.

Comment: Right, the issue is that `[scan %c $string]` returns 166 for **both** my Tcl and C++ generated characters.  If the problem were as you described, the `[scan %c |]` would return 124 (not 166).

Comment: @dan04: I am only able to type | [vertical line] from my keyboard. How did you type the [broken bar]?

Answer (score 4):

On my system, the tcl script `puts [format %c 166]` outputs in UTF-8 ("\xC2\xA6"), while the C++ statement `cout << "\xA6";` outputs Latin-1. Make sure encoding differences aren't throwing you off.